# Determine the number of irreducible polynomials of degrees 2, 3, and 6 over a prime ﬁeld.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, mobius-function

[Determine the number of irreducible polynomials of degrees 2, 3, and 6 over the prime ﬁeld $\mathbb F_p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638066)

My question is related to the answer posted for the above question. I was scratching my head to understand how you come up to f(2)=g(2)−g(1)−(g(1)2) polynomial degree 2 and that of degree 3. Any help with that is appreciated. Is there a general formula that we need to follow or depend up on? How could I fit Möbius function here?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: When you ask a question about what you don't understand in an answer (which is generally a good idea), try to be as specific as you can about what it is that you don't understand in the answer. In the present case, there's an entire paragraph before the equation that you quote that explains how that equation comes about. It would be easier to help you understand the equation if you told us which part(s) of that paragraph you don't understand.

Comment: Here is the answer given by: Hagen von Eitzen. 
All reducible polynomials of degree 2 are products of polynomials of degree 1. More precisely, we either have the square of a degree-1 polynomial - g(1) possibilities - or the product of two distinct polynomials - (g(1)2) because the order does not matter. We conclude that  f(2)=g(2)−g(1)−(g(1)2)=p2−p−p(p−1)2=p(p−1)2
 So I was trying to link the description above given by Hagen to the conclusion of the following: f(2)=g(2)−g(1)−(g(1)2)=p2−p−p(p−1)2=p(p−1)2.

Comment: That's a misunderstanding. I did follow the link and saw the answer, and I did understand that you were quoting the equation from there. My question was which part of that paragraph you don't understand. It won't help you much if we just repeat the explanation given there; we need to understand what part of it you find hard to understand in order to improve on it.

Comment: My misunderstanding arises between the premise and the conclusion given above by Hagen. I don't see any support or any reference given for the answer. May be I am lost  in the middle. Sorry if I bothered you. Clear explanation would help other page visitors as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hagen has made a valiant (and successful) attempt to give an elementary count of the irreducibles of low degree, but I think the more abstract and structural, more-or-less standard argument based on the use of Möbius Inversion is much more instructive.

Let $N_2$ be the number of quadratic irreducibles over the prime field $\Bbb F_p$. Now consider the quadratic extension of the field $\Bbb F_p$ of $p$ elements. This quadratic field has $p^2$ elements, which fall into two classes. Each element is either in $\Bbb F_p$ already, or its minimal polynomial is quadratic, with both roots in our field. (In fact, if $\alpha$ is one root, the other is $\alpha^p$.) Thus $2N_2$ is the count of this second class of elements. That is $p^2=2N_2+p$.
In other words, $N_2=\frac{p^2-p}2$.

Same thing for $N_3=$ number of cubic irreducibles. Consider the (unique!) cubic extension of $\Bbb F_p$, with $p^3$ elements. Again, the elements of *this* field fall into two classes, either an element is in $\Bbb F_p$ already, or it generates a subfield of degree $3$, i.e. the whole thing. (Can’t generate a quadratic extension because the field extension degree is $3$, which has only the two divisors.) Again, this cubic element’s minimal polynomial is cubic (and if you started with the cubic element $\alpha$, the other roots of its minimal are $\alpha^p$ and $\alpha^{p^2}$). So once again, $p^3=3N_3+p$, and $N_3=\frac{p^3-p}3$.

Comment: +1 *explicit* mention of Möbius inversion is pedagogically desirable here (else beginners may have difficulty grasping how the proof works).

Comment: Yeah, @Gone, probably. But in these cases, where the degree is prime, you can get away without MI. I didn’t want to blow OP away with stuff they may not know.

Answer (score 0):

I’m still not sure after the exchange in the comments whether I can say anything new that Hagen hasn’t already said, but I’ll give it a try.

By definition, a polynomial is reducible exactly if it is the product of two polynomials with positive degrees. A polynomial of degree $2$ can only be the product of two polynomials with positive degrees by being the product of two polynomials of degree $1$. These two polynomials of degree $1$ can either be the same or different. Since $g(1)$ counts the polynomials of degree $1$, it also counts the ways to get a polynomial of degree $2$ by multiplying a polynomial of degree $1$ by itself (i.e. squaring it). For the case of two different polynomials, we need to count the pairs of different polynomials of degree $1$, since we get the same polynomial of degree $2$ no matter in which order we multiply the two polynomials of degree $1$. There are $\binom{g(1)}2$ such pairs of polynomials of degree $1$.

Thus, there are $g(1)$ polynomials of degree $2$ that are reducible because they are the square of a polynomial of degree $1$, and $\binom{g(1)}2$ polynomials of degree $2$ that are reducible because they are the product of a pair of polynomials of degree $1$. This exhausts all ways in which a polynomial of degree $2$ can be reducible, so if we subtract these two counts from the count $g(2)$ of all polynomials of degree $2$, we get the count of irreducible polynomials of degree $2$: $g(2)-g(1)-\binom{g(1)}2$. Further up, Hagen had shown that $g(n)=p^n$, since each of $n$ coefficients can be chosen independently from $p$ values. Thus $g(2)-g(1)-\binom{g(1)}2=p^2-p-\frac{p(p-1)}2=\frac{p(p-1)}2$.

I’ve tried my best to make every step of the argument explicit. If it’s still not clear, please do point to a specific part of it that you need further explanation for.